# How can I exclude the bin folder from sourcesafe in a Visual Studio 2008 web application?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, web-applications, visual-sourcesafe

How can I exclude the bin folder from SourceSafe in a Visual Studio 2008 web application?  I want to be able to check in everything recursively from the solution node without picking up anything in the bin folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Right-click the folder in your
  project
- select "Exclude from project"

Comment: You can't exclude folder/directory from the project. "Exclude from project" command only available for files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could exclude files from source control in your projects.

For example (In Visual Studio), if you added the ConnectionStrings.config file to your project then select the ConnectionStrings.config file in the Solution Explorer and then select "Exclude ConnectionStrings.config from Source Control" from the File->Source Control menu. Now, your file will be ignored by Source Control and won't be checked into Source Control.

Note: If you right click on the ConnectionStrings.config file in Solution Explorer and bring up the context menu for it then there is a "Exclude From Project" menu item, THIS IS NOT the option to exclude from Source Control. So do not get confused between the "Exclude ConnectionStrings.config from Source Control" and "Exclude From Project"; they are not the same thing. "Exclude ConnectionStrings.config from Source Control" can only be accessed in the File->Source Control menu.

Comment: source: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b350f7f8-fc2b-4a66-8f3e-340c1c13d974/tell-vss-to-ignore-a-file-basically-like-ignore-in-cvs?forum=vssourcecontrol

Answer (score -1):

You can hide the folder through Windows explorer, although it'll disappear from your Visual Studio Solution Exporer, I don't think that'll affect the website.