# MS Build Server 2010 - Buffer Overflow // append: how to exclude directory from source safe

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-sourcesafe, build-server

I try to build an solution in MS Build Server (MS Visual Studio 2010 ver 10.0.30319.1) about ServerTasks -> Builds -> Server Task Builder -> Queue new Built and go, 47 seconds later I get an error output:

> CSC: Unexpected error creating debug information file 'c:\Builds\1\ServerTasks\Server-Tasks Builder\Sources\ThirdParty\Sources\samus-mongodb-csharp-2b8934f\MongoDB.Linq\obj\Debug\MongoDB.Linq.PDB' -- 'c:\Builds\1\ServerTasks\Server-Tasks Builder\Sources\ThirdParty\Sources\samus-mongodb-csharp-2b8934f\MongoDB.Linq\obj\Debug\MongoDB.Linq.pdb: Access denied

I checked the permissions of directory and set it (for debug purposes only) to grant access for all users, but still having an issue. Running the Procmon and filter file access for directory:

> 'c:\Builds\1\ServerTasks\Server-Tasks Builder\Sources\ThirdParty\Sources\samus-mongodb-csharp-2b8934f\MongoDB.Linq\obj\Debug\'

tells me:

> 16:41:00,5449813 TFSBuildServiceHost.exe 3528 QuerySecurityFile C:\Builds\1\ServerTasks\Server-Tasks Builder\Sources\ThirdParty\Sources\samus-mongodb-csharp-2b8934f\MongoDB.Linq\obj\Debug BUFFER OVERFLOW Information: DACL, 0x20000000

and

> 16:41:00,5462119 TFSBuildServiceHost.exe 3528 QueryOpen C:\Builds\1\ServerTasks\Server-Tasks Builder\Sources\ThirdParty\Sources\samus-mongodb-csharp-2b8934f\MongoDB.Linq\obj\Debug FAST IO DISALLOWED

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kockiren asked my to answer this thread after i found how to solve yesterday ...

This files which makes the problems here, are mostly this files, that will be generated while building the solution.

Simply remove them from source-control by 
1. go to Source Control Explorer in VS
2. klick on this files (or the folder in which they are)
3. and press DEL to remove them

After checking in the solution and the projects you built will run!

Answer (score 1):

What you should do with Procmon is to filter out all ACCESS DENIED records. Buffer overflow and fast IO disallowed can be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I found a thread here on stackoverflow ["How can I exclude the bin folder..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73212/how-can-i-exclude-the-bin-folder-from-sourcesafe-in-a-visual-studio-2008-web-appl) who tells me the problem is that i checked in the bin directory. To solve the problem I should right-click the bin directory and select "Exclude from project", but there isn't this option.

I try it with Source Explorer (VS2010 TFS), open the Source an right-click to the bin directory and context-menu with following entries will be open:

- Get Latest Version
- Get Specific Version
- Check Out for Edit
- Lock
- Unlock
- Delete
- Rename
- Undo Pending Changes
- Check In Pending Changes
- Shelve Pending Changes
- View History
- Compare
- Branching and Merging
- Move
- Apply Label
- New Folder
- Add Items to Folder
- Cloak
- Properties
- Refresh

I try to cloak the folder, but this option ist only for my workingcopy and not for Built Task. Any ideas, how to exclude the folder from Source Safe?